# What MediaWiki API to use?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I am new to Web Development.I am planning to access the MediaWiki database for a project so to do that I am not able to locate good tutorials. Any help and links to the tutorials will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki has an auto generated documentation that can be accessed with the entry point of the API https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php/

The other documentation here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Tutorial is pretty through too. This page also has a 50 minute video [Roan](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Catrope) gives a introduction to the API.

Additionally use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox%20//%20link) page to play around with the API until you get the parameters right.

Comment: Thanks! What about libraries list here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code ?